# Angular factory and Unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 Angular modules. rootModule:

```
var myModule = angular.module('rootModule', []);

myModule.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
    var sharedService = {};
    return sharedService;
});

myModule.factory('getMonthlyHistoryService', function ($http, $q) {
    var getMonthlyHistoryService = {};
    return getMonthlyHistoryService;
});

function RandomScaleController($scope, $rootScope, sharedService) {
}

RandomScaleController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'mySharedService'];
```

and Child module:

```
var modal = angular.module('modal', ['rootModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);
function MomController($scope, $http, sharedService, getMonthlyHistoryService) {
}
MomController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'mySharedService','getMonthlyHistoryService'];
```

All works fine, but if i move getMonthlyHistoryService into child module i got Error: Unknown provider: getMonthlyHistoryServiceProvider <- getMonthlyHistoryService.

How I can move getMonthlyHistoryService into child module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How module reference should be created would be to have multiple child modules linked\imported into the parent module

You have done the reverse. You have injected parent module into child module. Now if you move your service from parent to child only this module element can access this service.

Try 
`var myModule = angular.module('rootModule', ['modal']);`

and

`var modal = angular.module('modal', ['ui.bootstrap']);`

Also declare the controller using the `module.controller` syntax

```
modal.controller('MomController',['$scope', '$http', 'mySharedService','getMonthlyHistoryService',function($scope, $http, sharedService, getMonthlyHistoryService) {

}]);
```

Comment: I need move only getMonthlyHistoryService in child module. And rootModule not use getMonthlyHistoryService. rootModule use mySharedService, modal use mySharedService and getMonthlyHistoryService

Comment: The controller you have create are in global scope and are not part of the module. I think they have access to only the rootModule services. Create you controller using the `module.controller` method and it would work.